# Error in Build with Jekyll in GitHub pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, hugo, jekyll-theme

I'm new to web development, so please bear with me.

Im trying to create a Github page using hugo with the theme "[LoveIt](https://github.com/dillonzq/LoveIt)" upon building and testing it to my local machine it works fine. but when I push to my github repo. it was failing to build with Jekyll.

Below is the [error](https://github.com/xZhiLx/xzhilx.github.io/actions/runs/4258337348/jobs/7409467408) code:

`github-pages 228 | Error:  Liquid syntax error (line 26): Variable '{{</* style "text-align:right; strong{color:#00b1ff;}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/`

My [repo](https://github.com/xZhiLx/xzhilx.github.io)

I tried pushing the whole repo of the theme to edit the source of the error. but it wont let me push it because it was not a submodule.

Comment: The link to the `error` is not visible for us. Your latest "GitHub Actions" are "green" have you solved the issue yourself?